# Why is this ember test failing - Ember JS, Controllers

Tags: javascript, ember.js, qunit

```
var model, controller;

// Set up the controller in a new container.
// On tear down, set the variables to null,
// we reset  the app on setup.
module('User Edit Controller', {
    setup: function(){
        AisisPlanner.reset();
        controller = AisisPlanner.__container__.lookup('controller:user_edit');
        model = AisisPlanner.User.store.createRecord('user', {
            name: 'john doe',
            userName: 'john_doe',
            email: 'a@test.com',
            bio: '',
            pictureUrl: '',
            role: 'Administrator'
        });
        controller.set('model', model)
    },
    teardown: function(){
      controller = null;
      model = null
    }
});

test('capatalize_user_name', function(){
  model.set('userName', 'John doe')
  equal(controller.get('userName'), 'JOHN DOE', 'all caps');
});
```

The following test is simple to figure out what were doing, were setting up a controller from the current container and a model. Were then setting information in that model and using it in a test to canalize the name.

The issue is that I am getting the errors:

```
Setup failed on capatalize_user_name: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'AisisPlanner.User.store.createRecord')
```

and

```
Died on test #2 global code@http://localhost:3000/assets/controllers/user_edit_controller_test.js?body=1:26:5: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'model.set')
```

I got the idea from: [this blog post on how to test controllers.](http://codingvalue.com/blog/testing-emberjs-controllers/) I think its mostly out dated but I attempted it none the less. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for this test to pass, I had to do the following:

```
var model, controller;

// Set up the controller in a new container.
// On tear down, set the variables to null,
// we reset  the app on setup.
module('User Edit Controller', {
    setup: function(){
        AisisPlanner.reset();
        Ember.run(function(){
            controller = AisisPlanner.__container__.lookup('controller:user_edit');
            model = controller.get('store').createRecord('user', {
                name: 'Jhon Doe',
                userName: 'John_Doe',
                email: 'a@test.com',
                bio: '',
                pictureUrl: '',
                role: 'Administrator'
            });
            controller.set('model', model)
        });
    },
    teardown: function(){
      controller = null;
      model = null
    }
});

test('capatalize_user_name', function(){
    Ember.run(function(){
        model.set('userName', 'JOHN DOE')
        equal(controller.get('userName'), 'JOHN DOE', 'all caps');
    });
});
```

`Ember.run()` had to be around both the test and the setup of the controller/model it's self.

The test then had to be changed to SET the model userName as JOHN DOE, as set means you are setting something to it, thus the controller could not  be like "oh ya, john doe is capitalized."

Answer (score 0):

The store doesn't exist on the model Class, but it does on a controller

```
controller = AisisPlanner.__container__.lookup('controller:user_edit');
model = controller.get('store').createRecord('user', {....
```

Wrap any failing lines in an Ember run statement  (I'm not sure if this is the failing line or not, just an example)

```
Em.run(function(){
  controller.set('model', model);
});
```

Comment: Hah, definitely not, just a stutter typo, while typing left handed only.

Comment: This now throws two new errors: Setup failed on capatalize_user_name: Assertion Failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in an Ember.run
Source:  
http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:61
Died on test #2 global code@http://localhost:3000/assets/controllers/user_edit_controller_test.js?body=1:26:5: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'model.set')

Comment: I put an example of ember run in the answer, is model undefined in the test?

Comment: I posted an answer which solved my issue, not sure if this the correct approach but it made my test pass ...